# Meaning of "char *_EXFUN(index,(const char *, int));"

Tags: c

I found this as a proposition of the eclipse idexer/intelisence whatever the call it. And this is it:

```
char *_EXFUN(index,(const char *, int));
```

First it looks like a function returning a pointer for a char, but the parameters (if it is a function at all) looks to me quite confusing. How come into the parameter list we have a brackets.

Comment: `_EXFUN` is obviously a macro - you need to find its definition.

Comment: Search your header files for `_EXFUN`. And try to stop the compiler after preprocessing and see what it generates.

Comment: And by the way, where did you find this line of code? A name such as `_EXFUN` is not allowed in user code, only in code provided by a compiler or the standard library (as names starting with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter is reserved for "the implementation").

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It comes from an implementation of the standard library.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`_EXFUN` appears to be a macro used in standard headers on some platforms, e.g. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/examples/stdio_8h-source.html)

```
#ifndef _EXFUN
# define _EXFUN(N,P) N P
#endif
```

Thus, `char *_EXFUN(index,(const char *, int));` expands to

```
char * index(const char *, int)
```

This trick is sometimes done so that the same header can be preprocessed with `_EXFUN` set to something else, e.g. to introspect function signatures, or to declare exported symbols in a library.