# Function definitions of built-in functions in C

Tags: c, gcc, built-in, function-definition

We include header files like `stdio.h` in our C programs to use the built-in library functions. I once used to think that these header files contained the function definitions of the built-in functions that we may use in our programs. But soon found that it was not so.

When we open these header files (eg. stdio.h), all it has are function prototypes and I could see no function definitions there. I see things like this:

```
00133 int     _EXFUN(printf, (const char *, ...));
00134 int     _EXFUN(scanf, (const char *, ...));
00135 int     _EXFUN(sscanf, (const char *, const char *, ...));
00136 int     _EXFUN(vfprintf, (FILE *, const char *, __VALIST));
00137 int     _EXFUN(vprintf, (const char *, __VALIST));
00138 int     _EXFUN(vsprintf, (char *, const char *, __VALIST));
00139 int     _EXFUN(vsnprintf, (char *, size_t, const char *, __VALIST));
00140 int     _EXFUN(fgetc, (FILE *));
00141 char *  _EXFUN(fgets, (char *, int, FILE *));
00142 int     _EXFUN(fputc, (int, FILE *));
00143 int     _EXFUN(fputs, (const char *, FILE *));
00144 int     _EXFUN(getc, (FILE *));
00145 int     _EXFUN(getchar, (void));
00146 char *  _EXFUN(gets, (char *));
00147 int     _EXFUN(putc, (int, FILE *));
00148 int     _EXFUN(putchar, (int));
00149 int     _EXFUN(puts, (const char *));`
```

(source: https://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/examples/stdio_8h-source.html)

Then I was told that maybe the functions definitions must be in one of the header files included in the header file that we examine and so I believed for some time. Since then I’ve looked into a lot of header files but never found a single function definition.

I recently read that the function definitions of the built-in functions are not provided directly but is given in some special way. Is this true? If so, where are the function definitions of the built-in functions stored? And how are they brought into our programs since the header files only have their prototypes?

EDIT: Please note that I showed the contents of the header file just as a sample. My question is not about `_EXFUN` macro.

Comment: They do contain the proper definitions. After preprocessing.

Comment: Google linker, the process is called linking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "char \*\_EXFUN(index,(const char \*, int));"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545326/meaning-of-char-exfunindex-const-char-int)

Answer (score 4):

A 'prototype' is generally referred to as the function's declaration - this is what you will find in the header files. In this case, the prototype construction is aided by the `_EXFUN()` macro, and will be fully revealed by preprocessing.
The following command will pass `stdio.h` through the preprocessor and output the result to stdout:

```sh
gcc -E -x c /dev/null -include stdio.h
```

If you wade through the output, you'll find the expected prototypes (used as examples below), my system gives:

```c
extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);

extern int vfprintf (FILE *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __format,
       __gnuc_va_list __arg);
```

---

> I recently read that the function definitions of the built-in functions are not provided directly but is given in some special way. Is this true?

Yes, via libraries. If you're looking for the function's *implementation*, then you will need to look at the sources for the appropriate function. In this case, `stdio.h` is owned by a variant of 'The C standard library' - libc, or in my case glibc.

Header files should almost never include implementation details, and should instead just contain definitions for `struct`, `enum`, `typedef`, and function prototypes that need to be shared.

If you're looking for the implementation / source of `printf()` (as an example), then you will need to look at the library's source code.

It is quite unlikely that your toolchain will ship with the source code, it will probably include the libraries (`*.a` and `*.so`), and header files (`*.h`). Some package managers and libraries have two packages associated with them - for example: `mylibrary` and `mylibrary-dev`. In this case, the former will generally contain the library binaries, while the latter will contain the header files so that you may make use of the library in your application - neither package usually contain the sources.

it In my case (as mentioned above), the library is glibc:

- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=summary

As you're interested in `printf()`, then you'll need to look at `stdio-common/printf.c`:

- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/printf.c;h=ba84064e9e67e87311fc4d7fb0ebc28b7e6a83f6;hb=HEAD#l24

This is of course just a thin wrapper around `vfprintf()`.
It's at this point that you start to realise that some libraries are very large and complex... You can spend quite a bit of time trying to see 'through' macros to find your target function, which happens to be in `stdio-common/vfprintf.c`:

- https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;h=54b1ba2ac87ece033b0dcf95cbe43bf401b1aa33;hb=HEAD#l1233

---

> And how are they brought into our programs since the header files only have their prototypes?

One of the final steps of 'compiling' an application is 'linking'. There are two types:

## Static Linking

The machine code is taken from `*.a` files - static libraries.
These files are just archives (see `ar(1)`) containing object files (`*.o`), which in turn contain the machine code.

- Compile Time:
  The actual machine code for the specific function is copied into your binary.
- Run-Time:
  When your binary is loaded, it already has a copy of the `printf()` function. Job done.

## Dynamic Linking

The machine code is taken from `*.so` files - static libraries, or 'DLLs' - Dynamic-link library.
These files are binaries in their own right containing a set of symbols, or entry points that may be used.

- Compile Time:
  The linker will just ensure that the functions that you're calling exist in the shared libraries, and note down that they need to be linked at run-time.
- Run-Time:
  When your binary is loaded, it has a list of 'symbols' that need to be linked, and where they can be found.
  At this point, the dynamic linker (`/lib/ld-linux.so.2` for me) is invoked. In simple terms, the dynamic linker will then 'wire up' all of the shared library functions before your application executed. In reality, this can be deferred until the symbol is actually accessed.

---

As yet another extension... You have to be careful - compilers will often optimise expensive operations away.

The following simple use of `printf()` will likely get optimised to a call to `puts()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

Output of `objdump -d ${MY_BINARY}`:

```
[...]

000000000040052d <main>:
  40052d:       55                      push   %rbp
  40052e:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400531:       bf c4 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005c4,%edi
  400536:       e8 d5 fe ff ff          callq  400410 <puts@plt>
  40053b:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  40053c:       c3                      retq
  40053d:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)

[...]
```

For further reading, see here: https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html

Comment: *A 'prototype' is generally referred to as the function's definition* No, that would be the *declaration*.   ["A function definition in C programming consists of a *function header* and a *function body*."](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm)  See **6.7 Declarations** and **6.9.1 Function Definitions** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)  A function's *defintion* ***IS*** the *implementation*.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle - fixed

Comment: @Attie  _If you'e looking for the function's implementation, then you will need to look at the sources_ But where can I find these source in my computer? They got to be in the machine compiling the code right? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: @J...S they quite probably aren't on your computer. Toolchains tend to get shipped with the libraries (`*.a` and `*.so`), and header files. If you want the sources you'll have to locate them separately. You will often find that systems have `mylibrary` and `mylibrary-dev` packages - the former containing the library binaries, and the latter containing the headers. It is quite rare for packages to include the sources.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/m68hc11_install.html '*Installation with the sources requires that you get the sources of various GNU packages, apply a patch representing the 68HC11/68HC12 port and compile the whole set.*'

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/m68hc11_src.html - unfortunately many of the downloads appear to be missing...

Answer (score 2):

> I recently read that the function definitions of the built-in functions are not provided directly but is given in some special way. Is this true?

It may be true, depending on which compiler and compilers settings you're using. But we should back up a little bit.

First, you need to understand that there are many C libraries, where a library is a collection of functions that's compiled separately from your program. You include the header (.h) files that come with the library in your source code so that the compiler knows what you're talking about. After your code is compiled, it's *linked* with the libraries it uses, making the *definitions* of those library functions available to your program. In most cases, if you want to see how a function defined in a library is written, you need to look at the source code for that library. Including functions from libraries is standard stuff -- it doesn't qualify as "some special way" because it's not all that special. However...

Some functions from the C standard libraries are used so ubiquitously in C code that it makes sense for the compiler to have its own optimized versions of them. Depending on the compiler options you specify, the compiler may replace standard functions like `printf()`, `malloc()`, `fputs()`, `isascii()` and others with its own corresponding functions. You can find a list of the "builtin" functions for GCC [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins), along with a description of the compiler flags that allow or disallow their use. These functions *are* defined in a "special way" in that they get special treatment from the compiler, and you'd have to recompile the compiler itself if you want to change them. It's good to know that the standard library functions may be optimized this way, but it's not something that you should worry about in the normal course of writing code.